# Assign index page to my mobile site?

Tags: sub-menu

I was wondering how I can assign a different index page to my mobile site?
I tried some plugins like wp-mobile it changed colors and settings that I did not want done. Then I tried Mobile Menu but It only assigns menus to the drop down not the index to the page that opens up the site. So I still can't assign a different index page from my desktop site to my mobile site.

Comment: you can use a subdomain like in old times that points to your second index, you can use code server side with an IF in your default index page to render either the mobile version or the desktop version.

Comment: How would I do something like that, how would the code look like?